# Displaying object name in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to display the *.ps1 filename in my listview.

XAML:

```
  <ListView x:Name="script_pick"  Height="102" Loaded="Scripts_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Am I doing it right in my method? All that shows is WpfApplication2.Script in the listview, with four items when there's only two files.

```
 private void Scripts_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Scripts", "*.ps1");
            var scriptList = new List<Script>();

        foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(currentFile, true))
            {
                script_pick.Items.Add(new Script { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFile),
                                                   ScriptCode = sr.ReadToEnd()});

                sr.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set ItemsSource?

Comment: I suppose you are using something like Caliburn where the name is what you are binding to. Anyway, you can't set itemssource = {binding name}...what you probably want is to set a itemtemplate for each item of the listview

Comment: Tried that, it worked. The only question left is why each file is displayed twice in the GUI. The method must be called somewhere else, haven't figured out where yet tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the listView to the target collection, I guess this is script_pick.Items.

Then you have the smart way : add a datatemplate for the Script class so that xaml will know how to display it.

Or you can use the lazy (fast) way : just override ToString() on the Script class to display what you want (Script.Name) :)

BTW, you dont need to close StreamReader in the using block.